# Decryption with AES on server side in iOS(parameters to be know)

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

I have a registration process in my iOS app where the user is required to register himself or herself to login.So, I am sending this data to server,through soap requests,now what I want to do is encrypt the data before sending this to server, I got to know that iOS uses AES encryption mechanism to encrypt the data and it has CCCryptor.h files and i used this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    NSString *plainString = @"Hello Rob,Hello joseph";
    NSString *key = @"123456"; 

    NSLog( @"Original String: %@", plainString );

    NSString *encryptedString = [plainString AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
    NSLog( @"Encrypted String: %@", encryptedString );

    NSLog( @"Decrypted String: %@", [encryptedString AES256DecryptWithKey:key] );


    return YES;
}
```

this code works perfectly and I get correct outputs,if I pass this encrypted data to server,how this should be decrypted on server side is my doubt.(What parameters to use)

Also can we use a simple passphrase technique in my case ?

So friends,please help me out.

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1):

AES is the symetric key encryption. Which means both ends should use same key encrypt / decrypt. Here your key "123456" is to be used by the server to decrypt. But sending key along with encrypted string is no way secure.

Comment: hey thanks vignesh,for your reply, So, on server side what parameters should be know to decrypt,is it only key? and what algo should be used on server side to decrypt the data

Comment: @Ranjit Yes.The same what you have used.

Comment: here ios is using CCCrypt what is that ,,,, and whether,that should be used on server side?..by algorithm u mean AES256?

Comment: CCCrypt is the library name. Not algorithm name. Server should find some library for AES algorithm.

Comment: ok.thanks vignesh....I am not understanding this part of code       CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted );
can you explain me